# How to install JRuby-9.1.13.0 with Java 9?

Tags: java, macos, jruby, rbenv, java-9

I'm trying to install JRuby-9.1.13.0 with `rbenv` on MacOS.
The issue is that for some reason still Java 7 (1.7) is required, which no longer officially supported.

```
rbenv install --verbose jruby-9.1.13.0                                                                                 
ERROR: Java 7 required. Please install a 1.7-compatible JRE.

BUILD FAILED (OS X 10.13.1 using ruby-build 20170914)
```

The [JRuby wiki](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/GettingStarted#installing-jruby) mentions that Java SE should be installed, but not which specific version.
Installed is Java 9.

```
java -version 
java version "9.0.1"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.1+11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.1+11, mixed mode)
```

A Java 8 version is also installed.

```
jenv versions
  system
* 1.8 (set by /Users/<folder>/.java-version)
  1.8.0.152
  9.0
  9.0.1
  oracle64-1.8.0.152
  oracle64-9.0.1
```

Is Java 7 really a requirement for installing JRuby and therefor my setup is wrong?
Or is this an issue of JRuby or rbenv and installing JRuby should be also possible with Java 9 (Java 8)?

Comment: This may be the issue you are looking for: https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/issues/1135

Comment: Do take a look at this [comment on a commit](https://github.com/juanibiapina/ruby-build/commit/4889ec7ca64c59ed4fd4fae58d97c68cdc91434e#comments) further as well.

Comment: @AlanBateman & @nullpointer  thank you for pointing me in the right direction. Additionally i found out that my `jenv` setup isn't correct yet, because `java -version` reports still `java version "9.0.1" but should report `java version "1.8.x" for that directory. I will fix this later today and write an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIRC I fixed the `jenv` setup and switched to Java `1.8`, then I was able to install `JRuby`.